# Php checkboxes - what's missing ?

Tags: php, template-lite

i try to update ban and remove of user.

```
<tr>
    <td>{$user4.username}</td>
    <td>{$user4.email}</td>
    <td>{$user4.name} {$user4.surname}</td>
    {if $user4.banned}
    <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="banCheckNoBan" checked value="{$user4.id}"</center></td>
    {else}
       <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="banCheckBan" value={$user4.id}</center></td>
    {/if}
    {if $user4.status}
    <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="removeCheck"</center></td>
    {else}
      <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="removeCheck" checked></center></td>
    {/if}
</tr>
```

As you see above, if user is banned, checkbox is checked, remove is same.

however,

This is in my php side,
I do this, but it does not update why

```
if(isset($_POST['updateBanRemove'])){

               if(isset($_POST['banCheckBan']))
                   NCore::db('USER')->updateAsArray(array('BANNED' => 1))->eq('ID', $_POST['banCheckNoBan'])->execute(); 
               elseif(isset($_POST['banCheckNoBan']))
                   NCore::db('USER')->updateAsArray(array('BANNED' => 0))->eq('ID', $_POST['banCheckNoBan'])->execute(); 

            }
```

Comment: You forgot the closing `>` for your first three checkboxes...

Comment: yeap but this does not solves the problem :S

Comment: `print_r($_POST);` to see what's actually sent.

Comment: Is `updateBanRemove` also set?

Comment: Can you do an equivalent of print_r in your template engine? User4 is probably not set properly

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST['banCheckBan']))
    NCore::db('USER')->updateAsArray(array('BANNED' => 1))->eq('ID', $_POST['banCheckNoBan'])->execute();
```

You are using `$_POST['banCheckNoBan']` instead of `$_POST['banCheckBan']` in your query.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

1. you have a syntax errors - you dont close the `<input>` tag with `>`!
2. you should add `value="something"` attribute to the `<input type="checkbox">` tag.

Comment: A checkbox without a value is submitted with the value `on`.

Comment: it does not see else statement    <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="banCheckBan" value="{$user4.id}" /></center></td>

Comment: @Mert, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, really? Cross-browser valid?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#checkbox-state-type-checkbox => "The value IDL attribute is in mode default/on." => http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-apis.html#dom-input-value-default-on

Comment: @ThiefMaster, but this is HTML5. Now looking at HTML4, it states that the value attribute *"is optional except when the type attribute has the value "radio" or "checkbox"*!!! That means it is arbitrary for checkbox! See http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-value-INPUT

Answer (score 0):

This bit:

```
{if $user4.banned}
<td><center><input type="checkbox" name="banCheckNoBan" checked value="{$user4.id}"</center></td>
{else}
   <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="banCheckBan" value={$user4.id}</center></td>
{/if}
```

Should be:

```
{if $user4.banned}
<td><center><input type="checkbox" name="banCheckNoBan" checked value="{$user4.id}" /></center></td>
{else}
   <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="banCheckBan" value="{$user4.id}" /></center></td>
{/if}
```

Notice that the `input` tag needs to close: `/>`. You just went straight into `</center>`.